# SMTP Socket exception C#

Tags: c#, sockets, smtp

I have written a windows service in C# that communicates via the server using SMTP. This worked when running on my machine, it was then moved to a server however there is now an issue with communication. 
I have the following exception :

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.206.109:587
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have tried adding the port to the firewall so it will allow communication through but no effect. I am inexperienced with this error and I could not find any fix that worked, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something on your either your server or the SMTP, a firewall or something, is preventing your application from connecting to your SMTP server, or the SMTP is not on the same network as the application server, or the SMTP specified does not exist.

Comment: Well i am using the gmail smtp so that should be fine, so its the firewall on the server then

Comment: not necessarily - there could still be a configuration error if you are using the incorrect SMTP details (such as port number) when trying to connect to gmail.

Comment: So using "smtp.gmail.com" going out on port 587, this has worked before when used on another machine of mine.